# Does the Ubuntu kernel have EFI stub loader boot support?

Tags: boot, kernel, uefi

This question is regarding efistub booting.

I would like load the stock pre-compiled Ubuntu kernel directly from UEFI firmware its boot menu, using `efiboogmgr`.

Since which Ubuntu version can this be done without the need for a separate bootloader?

Comment: It can be checked with `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep EFI_STUB`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 12.10 and newer

All [Ubuntu kernels built since kernel 3.3.0](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EFIBootLoaders) have included the EFI stub loader feature in the kernel. That means all Ubuntu releases since 12.10.

#### Background

[Kernel build configuration can be checked with command](https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system#answer-287372) f.e.

- `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep EFI_STUB`, or
- for release 18.0 and later with `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep EFI_STUB`

Comment: On ubuntu 18.0 you have to `cat /boot/config-5.0.0-23-generic | grep EFI_STUB`

Comment: @user10607 What is the 18.0 output of `zcat /proc/config.gz | grep EFI_STUB`?

Comment: config.gz does not exist on my system. There are multiple locations for kernel config information. See https://superuser.com/questions/287371/obtain-kernel-config-from-currently-running-linux-system