# How to boot load the kernel using EFI stub (efistub) loader?

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I have Ubuntu 14.04 running in UEFI mode as only operating system, no dual-boot here. The kernel version is 3.13.0-24-generic. There is an EFI partition. In this case the EFI partition is not at the default `/dev/sda1` but at `/dev/sda3` because I did actually [convert BIOS mode to EFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509423/which-commands-to-convert-a-ubuntu-bios-install-to-efi-uefi-without-boot-repair). I have used the `grub-efi-amd64` package, though that actually loads GRUB boot menu from UEFI firmware boot menu (UEFI boot loads `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`).

I want to skip that double boot menu loading step, and boot faster, directly from UEFI into the kernel. The [Ubuntu kernels since 12.10 have "Kernel EFI stub loader"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510009/does-the-ubuntu-kernel-have-efi-stub-loader-boot-support) feature.

I know I do need to copy the Ubuntu kernel to the EFI partition (possibly rename) and create an entry in UEFI boot menu (for instance using `efibootmgr`). Which exact terminal commands are necessary to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The commands below are more generic then for kernel version 3.13.0-35 only.

#### 1. Mount the efi partition and copy the kernel files there

> `$ mount /dev/sda3 /boot/efi`
>
> `$ mkdir -pv /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/`
>
> ```
> $ cp -uv /boot/vmlinuz-* /boot/initrd.img-* /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
> '/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic' -> '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic'
> '/boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic' -> '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic'
> ```

#### 2. Change the kernel file name

Shorten the kernel file name by removing `-generic` because [there seems to be a 39 character length path limit](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60193-Going-GRUB-less-with-UEFI&p=309923&viewfull=1#post309923) and Rename kernel file(s) to end in `.efi`, this ensures compatibility with most systems

> ```
> $ for f in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz-*-generic; do mv -uv -- "$f" "${f//-generic/}.efi"; done
> '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic' -> '/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic.efi'`
> ```

<sup>The above name kernel file name shortening is not enough for a `dpkg` installed **mainline kernel**, because for example `/EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz-3.16.0-031600rc6.efi` without `-generic` is still 40 characters long.</sup>

#### 3. Add new entry to EFI boot menu

Replace `3.13.0-35` in this example with your specific kernel version

> `$ kv=3.13.0-35;efibootmgr -c -p 3 -L $kv -l \EFI\ubuntu\vmlinuz-$kv.efi -u root=/dev/sda1 initrd=\\EFI\\ubuntu\\initrd.img-$kv-generic ro rootfstype=ext4 debug ignore_loglevel libata.force=dump_id crashkernel=384M-:128M`

This new boot menu entry will become your default new boot choice.

<sup>You might not need the extra debugging parameters `debug`, `ignore_loglevel`, `libata.force=dump_id` and `crashkernel=384M-:128M`. `Initrd` must be present, otherwise boot hangs at "*Switched to clocksource tsc.*" because the root device sda1 cannot be opened.</sup>

Comment: I don't know how you figured this out but you are amazing. There is surprisingly little doc around this neat feature.

Comment: In case it isn't working for you try to put arguments of `-l` and `-u` in double quotes (or escape backslash manually). You can test if this is the issue by executing `efibootmgr -v` after you've added new entry to EFI boot menu.

Also, in case your machine has more than one disks (say a SSD and a HDD) then you'll need to specify one by `-d` which defaults to `/dev/sda` (see `man efibootmgr`)

Comment: is that 39 character length limit still around or has it since been changed?

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/EFIStub), this can be done in a few simple steps that *will survive a kernel update*.

Note: this assumes that you have an EFI partition mounted at `/boot/efi`.

1. Create `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-efistub` with the following contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   cp /vmlinuz /initrd.img /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/
   ```

   This is a hook that will be ran on kernel update to copy the latest kernel image and initrd to the appropriate location. Then make it executable and run it:

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-efistub
   sudo /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-efistub
   ```
2. Add the boot entry:

   ```
   sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdb -p 1 -L "Ubuntu (efistub)" -l /EFI/ubuntu/vmlinuz -u "root=/dev/sdb2 rw initrd=/EFI/ubuntu/initrd.img quiet splash"
   ```

   Don't forget to change the `-d` and `-p` arguments depending on where your EFI system partition is. In my case, it is /dev/sdb1, but this is likely to be different for you. You will probably also have to change the `root=` value in the kernel cmdline to your root partition.

   (You can change the label to anything you want by changing the `-L` parameter.)

   The boot entry you just added will become the default entry. And it won't break after a kernel update, since the hook will make sure `vmlinuz` and `initrd.img` are always updated.

Comment: Any way to get it to work with secure boot since on my HP laptop when I try this it gives a secure boot error (of course I can disable secure boot too)

Comment: It looks like you would have to [use cryptboot and some tools to sign the kernel first](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EFISTUB). It's a bit of a hassle especially if you're not using Arch (as there is no ready-to-use tool), so I'd just disable secure boot.

Comment: What about copying the .signed kernel ?

Comment: does this work on ubuntu also because I'm not seeing the `/vmlinuz` and `/initrd.img` links on my system when I do a `ls /`

Comment: for the record, seems like on ubuntu 22.04 they can be found under `/boot/vmlinuz` and `/boot/initrd.img` respectively.