# Disable Grub Menu Permanently. Should not appear even if the Shift / Esc keys are pressed

Tags: grub2

Is there a way to disable the grub menu completely? I already have it hidden and boot directly to Ubuntu. Now, I don't want it to appear even by pressing Shift / Esc keys during boot.

Comment: I understand *what* you are asking for, but not *why* you would want this.  Being able to access grub in the case of a kernel update causing system problems is valuable, and if grub is not shown during the boot process unless you do something, does it create a problem?

Comment: This is for a highly locked down systems which are meant for very limited purpose (kiosk web browsing). Don't want any one to play around and access the grub menu. Not having access to grub menu for emergencies is not a problem.

Comment: I don't have a direct answer, but Ubuntu can be [booted from EFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/510856/how-to-boot-load-the-kernel-using-efi-stub-efistub-loader) or [https://www.tecporto.pt/wiki/index.php?title=Booting_the_Linux_Kernel_without_a_bootloader](https://www.tecporto.pt/wiki/index.php?title=Booting_the_Linux_Kernel_without_a_bootloader), and alternatively you can set [passwords in Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords)

Comment: @CharlesGreen i am trying to do this https://www.tecporto.pt/wiki/index.php?title=Booting_the_Linux_Kernel_without_a_bootloader but stuck at the line `cp /usr/src/linux/arch/x86/boot/bzImage /boot/efi/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` i am with Ubuntu18.04.. what should i write instead of this line??

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Charles on EFI direct booting. Will give it a try next week and post back how it goes.

Comment: @PRATAP Here's another link that may help [https://blobfolio.com/2018/06/replace-grub2-with-systemd-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04/](https://blobfolio.com/2018/06/replace-grub2-with-systemd-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: @CharlesGreen 0k..i will go through it.. thank you...