# Grub does not detect encrypted Ubuntu on second disk

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, encryption

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on my first nvme drive, which lays inside an encrypted partition.
Now, I've installed Kubuntu 20.04 on my second nvme drive, using the live installer and selecting encryption for this new install as well.

After the installation, I entered inside ubuntu and run `update-grub` so that the grub could see the newly installed kubuntu, but this didn't happen. Grub is unable to see the new OS.

I bet it happened because the live installer created a `/boot` partition on the second drive and it was expecting the system to boot from that one, but I'm unable to figure how to start kubuntu.

What i tried and didn't work:

- forcing the boot on the second drive (from BIOS)
- running `os-prober` after `fschk -y` (following [this guide](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/fix-ubuntu-not-detecting-windows-10-partition-during-install/))
- playing with grub-customizer
- reinstalling kubuntu

What can i do next? How do I create a grub entry for the Kubuntu encrypted partition?

[Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bM58VP7Gjd/) you can find the output of `boot-info`. To be more precise `nvme1` is the drive were I have Ubuntu (from which I run the command), while `nvme0` is the drive where I installed Kubuntu.

Comment: Besure both installs are decrypted and mounted before running report, otherwise it will leave out essential info. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Thanks @oldfred for the hint. I updated the question with the pastebin link.

Comment: Are both installs named: vgubuntu-root. I do not know LVM nor encryption, but do not think you can use same name without confusion. You only have one UEFI ubuntu entry and it is using nvme1 for booting. you may be able to create another ubuntux entry for nvme0 with efibootmgr. Similar, but use /dev/nvme0n1 http://askubuntu.com/questions/510856/how-to-boot-load-the-kernel-using-efi-stub-loader or VI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789  and `man efibootmgr`

Comment: Try to select nvme0 in the UEFI/BIOS. It should be called like, boot override or something like that.

Comment: No the I'm pretty sure the second install has the name vgkubuntu, which is not showing and is part of the problem. 
I'm not quite understanding your comment though, you (and the answers you linked) refer to efi boot manager, but I was talking about grub. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Newo I did try to force boot on nvm0 from bios, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to add a custom entry to grub menu that will load grub configuration of the second os.

This works for me on ubuntu 20.04.

Note: this approach directly loads grub.cfg from the second OS's boot partition.
This is different from chainloading another grub.  For this to work, grub used in both OS-es should be somewhat compatible, and both should identify disks by some unique identifiers like uuids.

Edit `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to contain:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Other - grub' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'other-<uuid of boot partition of secondary OS>' {
  if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root  <uuid of boot partition of secondary OS>
  else
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <uuid of boot partition of secondary OS>
  fi
  configfile /grub/grub.cfg
}
```

You can get the uuids of all your partitions with

```
$ ls -l -a /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Then update grub (all this is to be done from your first OS):

```
sudo update-grub
```

If this succeeds, you should have another menu entry when booting called "Other - grub", and when you select it, the entire grub configuration of the second OS will be loaded and you will be able to boot the second OS as if you have booted directly to the second hard drive.

My full notes on this topic are [here](https://matbb.org/notes/2021-02-01-grub/).

Comment: What's the point of the `if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then`? It's executing the very same command: `search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root <uuid of boot partition of secondary OS>`...